# How do I make Flutter's Material Design 3 FAB as round as Material Design 2?

Tags: flutter, material-ui, material-design

The code I tried is the following code.

```dart
FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image]

This image is the code above.

I was able to make it look almost the same, but if there is a better way to do it, please let me know.

Comment: use `borderRadius` insted of `shape.circle`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, the [`FloatingActionButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) docs show the [`shape`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton/shape.html) property :)

```dart
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  shape: const CircleBorder(),
  // ...
),
```

Comment: One day I'll understand why Google has changed from Mat2 to Mat3...Mat2 was far way better IMHO